# Every time I merge from a given dataframe, I want to add a column that represents the merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to pandas, and I'm trying to figure out a way to add my trade history into my bitcoin dataframe. I am using 3 dataframes: bitcoin_df (per minute data), buys (could be any time), sells (could be any time). I have done this so that I can create a graph of bitcoin that also has my trade history on it.

Originally, I had to convert the format of the buys and sells dataframe by rounding to the nearest second. As you will see in the output, the bitcoin_df dataframe takes information from the 0th second of every minute.

I have concatenated the data, and I have also created two columns. I have even wrote the path for the computer to add the string to the column to the right. Now, I just need to set the column to "buy" whenever it merges with the buys dataframe, "sell" for the sells dataframe, and nothing for the bitcoin_df dataframe.

Here is some sample data from the csv files I'm using to make the dataframe.:
bitcoin_df.csv:

```
Open time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Date
YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00,39145.21,39226.08,39145.21,39207.17,130.24191,2021-01-15
2021-01-15 00:01:00,39213.18,39213.18,39023.24,39031.95,82.159228,2021-01-15
2021-01-15 00:02:00,39031.96,39189.57,39023.24,39184.01,89.64397,2021-01-15
2021-01-15 00:03:00,39185.62,39366.44,39160.92,39360.01,71.681691,2021-01-15
```

```
#,orderId,exchange,datetime,date,ticker,side,type,notional,size,price,fee,feeCurrency
0,############,EXC,YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,M/DD/YYYY,BTC-PERP,buy,maker,#####.####,#.####,#####,##.########,USD
1,############,EXC,YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,M/DD/YYYY,BTC-PERP,buy,maker,#####.####,#.####,#####,##.########,USD
2,############,EXC,YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,M/DD/YYYY, BTC-PERP,sell,taker,#####.####,#.####,#####,##.########,USD
3,############,EXC,YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,M/DD/YYYY,BTC-PERP,sell, maker,#####.####,#.####,#####,##.########,USD
```

The following is my code.

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
merged_df['combined_datetime'] = pd.concat([bitcoin_df['Opentime'], buys['datetime'], sells['datetime']]).reset_index(drop=True)

merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(by='combined_datetime').reset_index(drop=True)

merged_df['transaction_type'] = ''

** #The problem lies beyond here somewhere **
# Get the number of rows in the 'bitcoin_df' and 'buys' dataframes
bitcoin_rows = bitcoin_df.shape[0]
sell_rows = sells.shape[0]
buys_rows = buys.shape[0]

# Assign 'buy' to the 'transaction_type' column for 'buys' rows
merged_df.loc[:buys_rows - 1, 'transaction_type'] = 'buy'

# Assign 'sell' to the 'transaction_type' column for 'sells' rows
merged_df.loc[sell_rows:, 'transaction_type'] = 'sell'

merged_df.loc[bitcoin_rows:, 'transaction_type'] = ''
print(merged_df)
```

** This is the current output **

```
         combined_datetime transaction_type
0      2022-08-23 00:00:00              buy
1      2022-08-23 00:01:00              buy
2      2022-08-23 00:02:00              buy
3      2022-08-23 00:03:00              buy
4      2022-08-23 00:04:00              buy
...                    ...              ...
334190 2023-04-11 23:58:00                 
334191 2023-04-11 23:59:00                 
334192 2023-04-12 00:00:00                 
334193 2023-04-12 00:01:00                 
334194 2023-04-12 00:02:00                 

[334195 rows x 2 columns]
```

** and the output should look like this **

```
         combined_datetime transaction_type
0      2022-08-23 00:00:00              sell
1      2022-08-23 00:01:33              buy
2      2022-08-23 00:02:00              
3      2022-08-23 00:03:00              
4      2022-08-23 00:04:00              
...                    ...              ...
334190 2023-04-11 23:58:41              buy
334191 2023-04-11 23:59:00                 
334192 2023-04-12 00:00:10              sell
334193 2023-04-12 00:01:00                 
334194 2023-04-12 00:02:00              buy

[334195 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `assign` during the concat. You can then delete the `.loc[]` where you are creating the column:

```
merged_df['combined_datetime'] = pd.concat([bitcoin_df['Opentime'],
   buys[['datetime']].assign(transacation_type='buy'),
   sells[['datetime']].assign(transacation_type='sell')]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will create the column prior to the concat with the correct transaction type for each buy and sell dataframe.

OPs edit:

```
    merged_df['time'] = merged_df['Opentime'].combine_first(merged_df['datetime'])
    merged_df = merged_df.drop(['Opentime', 'datetime'], axis=1)
    merged_df = merged_df[['time', 'transaction_type']]
    print(merged_df)
```

Comment: I inputted this, and there was a small typo, so I fixed that. After that, I had a columns must be same length as key error.

code i used:
merged_df['combined_datetime'] = pd.concat([
    bitcoin_df['Opentime'],
    buys[['datetime']].assign(transaction_type='buy'),
    sells[['datetime']].assign(transaction_type='sell')
]).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: I just fixed up the code a little by putting it in chatgpt, I think now all there's left to do is merge the datetime and Opentime columns.

code I used: now it's setting merged_df = pd.concat([
    bitcoin_df[['Opentime']],
    buys[['datetime']].assign(transaction_type='buy'),
    sells[['datetime']].assign(transaction_type='sell')
]).reset_index(drop=True)

merged_df['transaction_type'] = merged_df['transaction_type'].fillna('')

Answer (score 0):

you should have to sort after the assigned value of buy/sell. and pandas concat dataframe by order as in the input first bitcoin_df,then buy and then sell. so modified code check if it works

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
merged_df['combined_datetime'] = pd.concat([bitcoin_df['Opentime'], 
buys['datetime'], sells['datetime']]).reset_index(drop=True)


merged_df['transaction_type'] = ''

** #The problem lies beyond here somewhere **
# Get the number of rows in the 'bitcoin_df' and 'buys' dataframes
bitcoin_rows = bitcoin_df.shape[0]
sell_rows = sells.shape[0]
buys_rows = buys.shape[0]

merged_df.loc[:bitcoin_rows-1, 'transaction_type'] = ''

 # Assign 'buy' to the 'transaction_type' column for 'buys' rows
merged_df.loc[bitcoin_row:bitcoin_row+buys_rows-1, 'transaction_type'] = 'buy'

# Assign 'sell' to the 'transaction_type' column for 'sells' rows
merged_df.loc[bitcoin_row+buys_rows:, 'transaction_type'] = 'sell'

merged_df = 
merged_df.sort_values(by='combined_datetime').reset_index(drop=True)
print(merged_df)
```